# login from nuxtjs to laravel/passport server

Tags: laravel, nuxtjs

I made api's using laravel, I am using laravel passport for authentication I want to send login request from nuxtjs to laravel backend but I'm getting *401 (Unauthorized)* with any credential from the database.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' }, 
          user: { url: '/user', method: 'get' }
        },
        clientId: '1',
        clientSecret: 'clientsecret'
      }
    }
},

modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
  ],

axios: {
    baseURL: "http://prostudent.test/api"
  },
```

**login.vue**

```
<template>
  <a href="#" @click.prevent="login">Login</a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    auth: false,
    email: "vuejs@gmail.com",
    password:"123456",
    methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        const data = { email: this.email, password: this.password }
        await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: data })
      } catch (e) {
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

login function in **AuthController.php**

```
 public function login(Request $request){
        try {

            if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
                /** @var  User $user */
                $user = Auth::user();
                $token = $user->createToken('app')->accessToken;
                return response([
                    'message' => 'success',
                    'token' => $token,
                    'user' => $user
                ]);
            }
        }catch (\Exception $exception){
            return response([
                'message' =>$exception->getMessage()
            ], 400);
        }
        return response([
            'message'=> 'invalid username/password'
        ], 401);
```

ps: I tried to do it like its mentioned [here](https://github.com/jmschneider/nuxt-laravel-passport-example/blob/master/nuxt/README.md) which says in nuxt.js set up "*You will need to copy the `.env.example` file to `.env` and populate it with values from laravel*." but I dont have .env file in my nuxtjs project should I create it manually? otherwise I noticed that he didn't do anything extra on the serverside to connect it with nuxtjs, all the work is done on nuxtjs side.

Answer (score 0):

please debug to see if it is the last return line that is being returned or something else.

if it's **not** that line being returned, it might be the issue from Auth/Nuxt property and it's failing to fetch user data without token property.

as far as I know, in newer version of Nuxt/Auth, you should define properties seperately and not in endpoint. try codes below and see if it helps.

```
strategies: {
  local: {
    token: {
      property: 'token',
      global: true,
    },
    user: {
      property: 'user',
    },
    endpoints: {
      login: { url: '/login', method: 'post'}, 
      user: { url: '/user', method: 'get' }
    }
  }
}
```